# Access selected values from dropdown

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to capture selected values of dropdowns to run some functions in a jsp page with bootstrap css in a Spring MVC application.I am able to send individual dropdown selected values from jsp to Controller but not able to get them back to jsp for my use.What should be done.I have tried

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("emp",empid)

${sessionScope.emp}
```

but its not giving me currently selected value in dropdowns

Furthermore I want to persist the selcted values in all dropdowns and use the currently selected only.Kindly help

Comment: Add the selected value to model attribute and send model to jsp page. like   `model.addAttribute("attributename","value")` and get in jsp using    `${attributename}`

Comment: Raaj I suggest you this edit, but you declined it and edit it by you self. It's fine, because you still new to this. But don't do such things in future, good luck

Comment: @ypp I have done that but still not able to get any values in jsp

Comment: can you please add code snippet which you are doing for this

Comment: @RequestMapping(value= "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String home2(@RequestParam("store") int store, @RequestParam("dept")int dept,@RequestParam("slot")int slot,@RequestParam("nahead")int nahead,@RequestParam("empid")String empid,@ModelAttribute Model model) throws ScriptException,ScriptException, IOException, ServletException {
  
  
  System.out.println(store +" " + dept+" "+slot+" "+nahead+" "+empid);
  
 System.out.println("Empid in IC1: "+empid );
  model.addAttribute("idemp", empid);
  model.addAttribute("empl","10000");
   return "/WEB-INF/views/index3.jsp";
 }

Comment: @ypp..Can you plz help in this

Answer (score 0):

> code to display selected drop down item using jstl is given below:

```
 <c:forEach items="${contentCat}" var="item">
       <option value="${item.cat_name}"  ${not empty selectListId && selectListId == item.cat_name ? 'selected' : ''}>
       <c:out value=" ${item.cat_name}"></c:out>  />
       </option>
</c:forEach>
```

> where contentCat is the list of class object and selectListId is value
>   of selected id
>
> you can add the session value  in the ModelAndView object then
>   forwarded to the view part

Comment: <div class="dropdown">
    <b>Select Store</b><br><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu5" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="selection">1</span>       
       <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu5">
         <c:forEach var="Store_id" items="${obj.dataStore}">
                                   <li><a> ${Store_id}</a></li>
                                   </c:forEach>

Comment: Kunal I Have added my dropdown code.how should I fit your code.Can you plz help again.thx

Answer (score 0):

The thing is I am able to get model attributes on loading my jsp for the 1st time but when I click dropdown and capture its value in Controller by sending through ajax and then add it to model through addAttribute,now I cannot get that value on my jsp

public String home2(@ModelAttribute("empid")String empid,BindingResult result,Model model) throws ScriptException,ScriptException, IOException, ServletException {

```
    model.addAttribute("empidp", empid);
```

}

${empidp}

Comment: Can anybode help me in this regard